# rails comments in a post ajax load more

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a standard `will_paginate`, but I want a button to load more comments, like Instagram. I searched many solutions, but I couldn't apply it to my project.

posts/index.html.erb

```erb
<%  @posts.each do |post| %>
<p><%= pluralize(post.comments.count, "Comment") %></p>
 <div id="comid_<%= post.id %>"></div>
 <div id='comments'>
   <% @comments = post.comments.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC") %>
   <%= render @comments %>
  <%= will_paginate @comments, :class =>"pagination" %>
 </div>
```

Github [my instagram_clone](http://www.example.com/)

Heroku [my instagram_clone](http://www.example.com/)